User uid in Firebase custom email verification handler
Is there a way to get any of the requesting user info (say uid or email) in Firebase custom email verification handler?

I don't think so, but I also don't think that's normally needed for what a handler is meant to do. It sounds a bit like a XY problem. If you edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish and show how you've already tried to accomplish this, we/somebody may be able to better help with that.

Thank you. I was able to get the previousEmail and email field and that helped me identified the user.
